# Почему python не создаёт PATH, а выдаёт ошибку "Couldn't launch python"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, python-3.10

Решил поиграть с нейросетью, скачал для этих нужд `webui`. Он запускается через батник, а для запуска нейронки нужен ещё и [python](/questions/tagged/python). Мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
Couldn't launch python
exit code: 9009
stderr:
Python
Launch unsuccessful. Exiting.
```

Посмотрел на форумах похожие ошибки, народ пишет о том, что при установке Питона надо поставить галочку, чтобы тот ещё и создал PATH. Устанавливаю, всё делаю как надо. Автоматически путь не создаётся. Пробую создать вручную, а оно тоже не видит. С чем это может быть связано?

Батник:

```
@echo off

if not defined PYTHON (set PYTHON=python)
if not defined VENV_DIR (set "VENV_DIR=%~dp0%venv")


set ERROR_REPORTING=FALSE

mkdir tmp 2>NUL

%PYTHON% -c "" >tmp/stdout.txt 2>tmp/stderr.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto :check_pip
echo Couldn't launch python
goto :show_stdout_stderr

:check_pip
%PYTHON% -mpip --help >tmp/stdout.txt 2>tmp/stderr.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto :start_venv
if "%PIP_INSTALLER_LOCATION%" == "" goto :show_stdout_stderr
%PYTHON% "%PIP_INSTALLER_LOCATION%" >tmp/stdout.txt 2>tmp/stderr.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto :start_venv
echo Couldn't install pip
goto :show_stdout_stderr

:start_venv
if ["%VENV_DIR%"] == ["-"] goto :skip_venv
if ["%SKIP_VENV%"] == ["1"] goto :skip_venv

dir "%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\Python.exe" >tmp/stdout.txt 2>tmp/stderr.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto :activate_venv

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('CALL %PYTHON% -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"') do set PYTHON_FULLNAME="%%i"
echo Creating venv in directory %VENV_DIR% using python %PYTHON_FULLNAME%
%PYTHON_FULLNAME% -m venv "%VENV_DIR%" >tmp/stdout.txt 2>tmp/stderr.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto :activate_venv
echo Unable to create venv in directory "%VENV_DIR%"
goto :show_stdout_stderr

:activate_venv
set PYTHON="%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\Python.exe"
echo venv %PYTHON%

:skip_venv
if [%ACCELERATE%] == ["True"] goto :accelerate
goto :launch

:accelerate
echo Checking for accelerate
set ACCELERATE="%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\accelerate.exe"
if EXIST %ACCELERATE% goto :accelerate_launch

:launch
%PYTHON% launch.py %*
pause
exit /b

:accelerate_launch
echo Accelerating
%ACCELERATE% launch --num_cpu_threads_per_process=6 launch.py
pause
exit /b

:show_stdout_stderr

echo.
echo exit code: %errorlevel%

for /f %%i in ("tmp\stdout.txt") do set size=%%~zi
if %size% equ 0 goto :show_stderr
echo.
echo stdout:
type tmp\stdout.txt

:show_stderr
for /f %%i in ("tmp\stderr.txt") do set size=%%~zi
if %size% equ 0 goto :show_stderr
echo.
echo stderr:
type tmp\stderr.txt

:endofscript

echo.
echo Launch unsuccessful. Exiting.
pause
```

Path:

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\libnvvp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\WireGuard\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2022.3.0\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\user\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\bin
```

python -V:

```
C:\Users\user>python -V
Python
```

where python:

```
C:\Users\user>where python
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
```

Comment: просто питон без всяких нейросетей и webui запускается?

Comment: Сам Питон исправно работает. Проблема возникает лишь с webui и path соответственно.

Comment: Ну а что в "батнике"?

Comment: Бат просто запускает пользовательский интерфейс для нейронки в браузере, как я понимаю.

Comment: Что. В. Батнике

Comment: Извините, в бат файлах не разбираюсь. Могу лишь буквально скопипастить содержимое

Comment: Да, желательно в тело вопроса. А еще приложите вывод команд python -V и path из вашей командной строки.

Comment: Разве вывод path и переменные среды в свойствах системы - не одно и то-же? Я бы просто тогда скринами всё прикрепил

Comment: В тело вопроса содержимое bat-файла и вывод команд: python -V и path. Это так просто.

Comment: Загляните в C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310 - есть такой путь в системе (папка такая)? Что в ней?

Comment: В ней лежит сам Питон. Он туда у меня по умолчанию устанавливается.

Comment: python -V выдаёт просто "Python" - скопируйте в тело ответ как есть, команда и ответ

Comment: Что дает команда where python

Comment: Удалите Python, установленный из магазина приложений Windows, скачайте и установите с сайта python.org.

Comment: Вывел решение в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зайдите в свои переменные окружения

Удалите дубли (всё же) в Path

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

Затем расположите в таком порядке

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\    
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

Вот готовое для вас:

`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\libnvvp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\WireGuard\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2022.3.0\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\user\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\bin;`

Затем, запустите `where python`. Проверьте результат и сравните с тем, что у вас в теле вопроса.

Запустите в новом окне cmd команду `python -V`.
Ответом должно быть что-то вроде

```
C:\Users\user>python -V
Python 3.10.0
```

Затем запустите ваш bat-файл. Желательно из нового окна командной строки. Просто перетащите bat-файл на новое окно cmd, если не знаете, как запускать.